# A way to always use Shift with number keys

Tags: keyboard, typing

Is there a way to simulate <kbd>Shift</kbd> being pressed whenever the number row at the top of the keyboard is used? I'm on Vista and would appreciate an app or registry tweak.

I am having little finger issues, so I would like to use the numeric keypad for typing numbers, and not be constantly holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> for typing these characters: !"£$%^&*()

Comment: Excellent question, but it's not programming related.

Comment: Keyboard layout is very much programming related IMHO

Comment: from the submit page 

"Is your question about programming?
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Write clearly and simply."

While I feel this is a question that can be answered in a consise & objective fashion, you are quite correct, apologies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [Layout Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/globaldev/tools/msklc.mspx) from MS, maybe that can help you.

Comment: Thankyou Thankyou Thankyou! It took 10 mins to setup, and the language systray icon makes swapping layouts a breeze.

Fortunately I am on x86 vista, 64bit have some issues, discussed here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2006/09/13/752086.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Caps Lock?

Comment: Caps Lock doesn't work on the number row. The exclamation point is not a capital one.